# Vuejs how to pass data from main.js to App.vue with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue where the App component and HelloWorld component are not getting passed data from main.js. This should be a rather simple thing to do in Vue. 
[image: vue counter 10]

You can see in the image that the root element has counter defined as 10, it's just not being populated in any of the child components. almost like line 12 in main.js is not taking any effect. If I click  and  it says 'counter: undefined'. What am I doing wrong? I've been beating my head against the wall for a few hours now.

Here is my main.js

```javascript
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({

  components: {App},
  data: {
    counter: 10
  },
  template: '<App :counter="counter" />',
  //computed: {
  //  counterInc: function () {
  //    return this.counter++
  //  }
  //},
  methods: {
    updateCounter (x) {
      this.counter = x
    }
  },

  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here is my App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Our Message" :counter="counter"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: ['counter'] ,
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Here is my helloworld.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>
      Here lies all of our operations for automating some strenuous tasks. <br>
    </p>
    <h3>Get Started {{ counter }}</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a v-on:click="updateCounter()" class="generateRollup">Generate Purchase Price</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
    counter: String,
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #0093D0;
}
.generateRollup:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: are sure that this code doesn't generate errors?

Comment: Yes 100% sure, I'm looking in chrome console and see no errors, also '"vue-cli-service serve' returns no errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I don't personally use the `render` function much, but what you can do to get your code working is supply the initial template in the actual html page and mount the Vue instance to it. I've made a codepen here : https://codepen.io/crustyjew/pen/jeWPgY

The essentials are to remove your `render` function, add the following to html

```
<div id="app">
  <app :counter="counter" />
</div>
```

leaving `.$mount('#app')` to mount it to that html you provide.

Comment: Looks like I can't remove the render function because I get a warning when removing it.  -
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Comment: Since I couldn't remove the render I researched a bit and I created a vue.config.js with the contents
`// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
`
in the root directory and removed the render: line and applied your edits. It is working flawlessly now. What are the caveats of using the compiler included build vs the way I was doing it?

Comment: I think they go into a bit of the difference on the official documentation site, but basically how I understand it is that the one with the template compiler is a little "heavier" and the one without can be used as a lighter version if you are doing all the template compiling yourself which can be helpful in certain CORS and content security situations.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the template compiler-included vue build, then you can implement a `render` function like this to pass prop values:

```
render: h => h(App, {
  props: {
    'counter': 10
  }
})
```

(Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments - the `h` argument of `render` functions is an alias for `createElement`.)

Answer (score 1):

Matti gave you already an answer, but you may want to think about your project structure. It shouldn't be the goal to pass data from your root component to the lowest child component.
In your case you have two options:

1. Use events to emit an event from your component to update the state in another component. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html for more information.
2. Use a state management like vuex. Vuex is used to handle you state globally. You can access the state with getters from all your components, without passing your data manually to each component, which needs access to the data. Furthermore vuex provides actions/mutations, which allows you to update the state. For more information see https://vuex.vuejs.org/.

For small projects vuex might be to much overhead for an equal result. But if you project gets bigger and bigger it's really hard to know what's going on in your components, when passing data through multiple components.

Comment: _"It shouldn't be the goal to pass data from your root component to the lowest child component."_
Why shouldn't I have a goal to do this? I have things happening in main.js that need to propagate to children. Are you saying children shouldn't be aware of their parents and parent data?

I will look into vuex. Thank you!

Comment: Yes indeed, components should be only responsible for itself. Except the case you have something like eg. a ListComponent and an ItemComponent, then it's okay to pass your props as mentioned. But if getting more complex like passing props to various components and also in deep it's usually better to use events or vuex. Hope it's more clear now.